Flutter: "Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1" and Emulator/Android Studio Issues
I've been encountering multiple issues while running a Flutter app on my Windows 10 laptop using Android Studio and an emulator. Here are the specific problems:
1.Error Message: When I try to run my Flutter code, I receive the following error:
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

2.Android Studio Crashes: Android Studio often behaves erratically:
It sometimes shuts down automatically when I run my code.
Occasionally, it displays an "Out of memory" message, although I have plenty of space on my system.
3.Emulator Issues: The Android emulator doesn't start as well.
System Information:

Operating System: Windows 10 (Version 10.0.22631.3737)
Flutter Version: 3.19.6 (Channel stable)
Android Studio Version: 2023.3
Android SDK Version: 34.0.0
Visual Studio Version: Community 2022 17.9.6
Other IDEs: VS Code 1.90.2
Here's the output of flutter doctor:

[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3737], locale en-US)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.9.6)
[√] Android Studio (version 2023.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.90.2)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] Network resources
No issues found.



I’ve checked for updates and confirmed that all relevant tools are up to date.
I've tried restarting Android Studio and the emulator.

Questions:

How can I resolve the "Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1" error when using a physical device?
What could be causing Android Studio to crash and display "Out of memory" errors?
Why isn’t the Android emulator starting?
Any guidance or troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

